# Why does my Jupyter lab wont read my cartopy package

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-lab, cartopy

Hello2,

I have downloaded cartopy on my anaconda navigator after several times that it wont let me download on my base(root) environment. I was able to install it first on a new package but from some reason it wont read on my jupyter lab. so I tried installing it again in my base(root) environment. When I finally had it installed, I still cant import cartopy.

[image]

Comment: some comments... 1) are you sure you restarted the kernel and use the right python-evironment? 2) did you try it on a fresh virtual environment?

Comment: also... try executing `!conda list` in a code-cell to see the installed packages in your current environment